# Sort multidimensional array by field end_date ASC

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

I'm trying to sort my array by the field end_date ASC

this is my array (containing more data, and sometimes the same date)

```
0 (Array, 5 elements)
    type (String, 5 characters ) short
    description (String, 8 characters ) textext
    enjoyed (Boolean) FALSE
    start_date (String, 24 characters ) 2013-12-03T01:00:00.000Z
    end_date (String, 24 characters ) 2014-01-26T01:00:00.000Z

1 (Array, 5 elements)
    type (String, 5 characters ) short
    description (String, 4 characters ) text
    enjoyed (Boolean) FALSE
    start_date (String, 24 characters ) 2013-12-19T01:00:00.000Z
    end_date (String, 24 characters ) 2014-06-25T02:00:00.000Z

2 (Array, 5 elements)
    type (String, 5 characters ) short
    description (String, 17 characters ) black en Platinum
    enjoyed (Boolean) FALSE
    start_date (String, 24 characters ) 2013-12-13T01:00:00.000Z
    end_date (String, 24 characters ) 2014-01-31T01:00:00.000Z
```

This is my attempt:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    global $array;
    return strcmp($array[$a]['end_date'], $array[$b]['end_date']);
}

uksort($array, 'cmp');
```

But the result is

```
1 
1
1
1
```

Where is it going wrong? At the dateformat?

Can someone point me into the right direction or provide assistance?

Comment: Why do you use `uksort` when you need the values anyway? Check out: [`usort`](http://php.net/usort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this function to sort every multidimensional array by one of his columns :

```
function sortArrayBy($array , $column_name,$sort=SORT_DESC){
  foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
   $column[$key]  = $row[$column_name];
  }
  array_multisort($column, $sort, $array);
  return $array;
 }
```

Call it like this :

```
<?php sortArrayBy($yourArray,'end_date',SORT_ASC) ; ?>
```

Comment: great thanks for this snippet, it did work :) I'll keep using it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
?>
```

Ref : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php